# stored procedures in scala.dbc

Tags: scala, jdbc

I wonder if scala.dbc supports stored procedures?

The mysql jdbc backend I'm using supports it, bonus points for a code illustration to show how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any work going on on Scala dbc anymore. You would have to wait for Scala dbc3, but I have no idea what the status of that is at the moment. You had better look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362748/wanted-good-examples-of-scala-database-persistence for an excellent overview of alternatvie Scala SQL frameworks. I don't believe that any of the ones mentioned in the link support stored procedures out of the box, however.